# How to include role information in Meteor's new user registration UI using ReactJS

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am following the official Meteor/React tutorial to build a React-based user registration UI (https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/adding-user-accounts). The tutorial indicates that I can build a React-based user registration feature using a Blaze wrapper:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { Blaze } from 'meteor/blaze';

export default class AccountsUIWrapper extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
  // Use Meteor Blaze to render login buttons
  this.view = Blaze.render(Template.loginButtons,
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.container));
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Clean up Blaze view
    Blaze.remove(this.view);
  }
  render() {
    // Just render a placeholder container that will be filled in
    return <span ref="container" />;
  }
}
```

This wrapper would allow someone to set user name and password when creating a new user. I wanted to extend it so that the role can also be specified for the new user.

Meteor's **Accounts.ui.config** doesn't seem to support a config option that will include a role field in the registration UI. I understand that I can use the `alanning:roles` package to assign a role to a user. However, I am struggling to find a way to integrate the `alanning:roles` package with the Blaze wrapper.

Is it possible to add something similar to the code snippet below to the Blaze wrapper?

```js
var id = Accounts.createUser({
    username: username,
    password: password
});

Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, ['admin']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a custom method in your component that looks something like the following:

```
register(event) {
  // Stop the default behavior when the button is clicked
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get the data from the DOM elements and clean it up
  var username = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.username).value.trim();
  var password = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.password).value.trim();
  var role = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.role).value.trim();

  // Set up the user object with the input data
  var options = {
    username: username,
    password: password,
    role: role,
  };

  // Create the new user with the data
  Accounts.createUser(options);

  return false;
}
```

Then, in your registration form, render a registration form using either `onSubmit = { this.register }` on the first `<form>` element or `onClick = { this.register }` on the submit button.